# Mongoose Select Method Not Working As Expected

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Trying to simply include a field that has select set to false within the schema. Overriding it with select method is not working for some reason. Exclusion of other fields work but inclusion doesn't. In the following example I'm trying to include the "active_account" field. What could be causing this behavior?

**Schema**

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    active_account: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
        select: false
    }
})
```

**Function**

```
exports.deactivate_user = async ( req , res , next ) => {
    
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( req.params.id , { active_account: false } ).select( '+active_account' );
    
    res.status( 200 ).json({
        status: 'Success',
        data: user
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate);

> A.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options)  // returns Query

So,

```
 const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate( 
                                           req.params.id, //id
                                           { active_account: false }, //update
                                           { select: 'active_account', new: true } //options
                                          );
```

set `new = true` to get the updated version of data.

Comment: What you said makes sense but it's not working with the changes. Your specific code returns nothing, even when I add the "+" in front to specify inclusion. A quick wildcard test with "+*" still doesn't include the active_account field. Very confused by this.

Comment: Adding the "-" will however remove a different field.

Comment: including + worked for me ,like this
`const demo = await Demo.findByIdAndUpdate(
      objects[1]._id, //id
      { active_account: false }, //update
      { select: "+active_account", new: true } //options
    ); `